# Tmux: Error messages from another window are getting overlaid over Vim's buffer

Tags: postgresql, vim, psql, tmux

I am using Tmux for terminal window management. In my usual workflow vim and PostgreSQL's `psql` session are open in separate windows.

From time to time, if i get an error after executing a query in `psql`, its contents are dumped onto vim's buffer contents. Issuing vim's `:redraw!` command helps. But maybe there's a more proper way of fixing this?

Thanks!

Comment: how are you creating the Tmux session?

Comment: @byaruhaf I am using OS X Terminal - i just type `tmux` in Terminal.